# How can I create new dataframes using for looping and the method query to filter my dataframe that already exist?

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe, for-loop

I want to create new dataframes using method query and a for looping, but when I try to make this happen
this error appears `UndefinedVariableError: name 'i' is not defined`.

I tried to do this using this code:

```
for sigla in sigla_estados:
    nome_estado_df = 'dataset_' + sigla 
    for i in range(28):
        nome_estado_df = consumo_alimentar.query("UF == @lista_estados[i]")
```

My list (`lista_estados`) has 27 items, so I tried to pass through all using `range`.

I couldn't realize what is the problem, I am beginner.

Comment: Do they all need to be separate dataframes or could each row of a single dataframe be a different item in the list?

Comment: For the question as written, try `f"UF == {lista_estados[i]}"`.  But I would consider if there's a way to store all your data in one dataframe, especially if all the items in your list would have the same columns

Comment: Also instead of `range(28)` do `range(len(lista_estados))`

Comment: `i` is propably not evaluated inside that string.

Answer (score 0):

From your code I suppose you want to create multiple dataframes, each one of them containing the rows in **consumo_alimentar** that apply to one specific country (column **UF** with a name that matches the country names in **lista_estados**).

I also assume that you have an array (**sigla_estados**) that contains the country codes of countries in **lista_estados** and that have the same length that **lista_estados** and arranged in such a way that the country code of **lista_estados[x]** is equal to **sigla_estados[x]** for all x.

If my assumptions are right, this code could work:

```
for i in range(len(lista_estados)):
    estado = lista_estados[i]
    sigla = sigla_estados[i]
    mask = consumo_alimentar['UF'] == estado
    nome_estado_df[sigla] = consumo_alimentar[mask]
```

With that code you'll get an array of data frames that I think is more or less what you want to. If you want to use the query method, this should also work:

```
for i in range(len(lista_estados)):
    estado = lista_estados[i]
    sigla = sigla_estados[i]
    query_str = "UF == @estado"
    nome_estado_df[sigla] = consumo_alimentar.query(query_str)
```